# Case sensitive find in Rails

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, find, collation, case-sensitive

I'm using Mysql with collation `utf8_general_ci` and for most of my searches it is good. But for one model and one field I want to find a record with case **sensitive**. How to do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is MySQL that is doing the case insensitive query, not Ruby on Rails.

See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/case-sensitivity.html

You could make database columns, that require case sensitivity to be case sensitive

1. Modify fields to be [BINARY](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/binary-varbinary.html) or [VARBINARY](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/binary-varbinary.html) instead of CHAR and VARCHAR.
2. Modify fields to have binary collation (e.g. latin1_bin)

-

```
 create table tbl_name (
    ...
    data varchar COLLATE latin1_bin
 )
```

Or you can modify your queries to use COLLATE operator:

`SELECT * from tbl_name WHERE col_name COLLATE latin1_bin LIKE 'a%'`

Comment: Yes, I know, but I want to find it in rails with case sensitive when all other searches are case insensitive

Comment: I know how to do it in MySql. I was asking how to do it in Rails. I already did it with Model.find_by_sql but I'm looking for cleaner solution.

Comment: Basically either mysql uses datatypes for columns that have case sensitive property or SELECT query forces matching to be case sensitive. Ruby-on-rails does not affect the former and I do not know any other way to do the latter than using Model.find_by_sql

Answer (score 0):

If you always want to search that column in a case sensitive manner, the best thing would be to define it with collation utf8_bin